# How Can I Tell If My Web Page Is Too Large For Google Crawler?

Tags: seo

Here is the situation: I have a client who runs a web site selling various smart toys. Every toy has one page on which four tabs describe its features, manual, after-sells-services-agent and  comments, respectively.

One of the toy which seems very intricate has a very long features tab as well as enormous manual(almost 70 images). In the perspective of SEO, I believe is too large for Search Engines to consume. Therefor I think it is hurting my SEO efforts because of that.

That is why I persuade my client to either delete some of the content which I believe useless or make a new page and put this manual on it, or whatsoever if emit manual is not good for it users.

The impediment I have is that I need to show some evident to this client. However, except telling him it is not good for SEO if we have pages which have large number of content on one page. I can not get anything obvious.

Anyhow, every SEO expert says page with large volume of content is not good, but how much volume is large volume?

I checked Google's cache of that page which shows all of the content on that page is cached for sure. Does it means that page is not too large for Google?

Please help me.

Comment: @Anon often known as `They` or `Them` or, just to scare you, `The Others`. I have a gaggle of Them outside my window at night, singing me to sleep, or keeping me awake, depending on which set of experts you ask.

Comment: Unfortunately, SEO questions are off-topic on StackOverflow. Frustrating, we know. That's why we invite those interested in SEO to consider supporting the ["White Hat SEO"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1/white-hat-seo) suggestion for a new StackOveflow-style Q/A system on Search Engine Optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Page load time is a negative factor in Google's determination of page quality, which affects the page's ranking (see, for example, [here](http://searchengineland.com/google-adds-page-load-time-to-quality-score-algorithm-13513)).  A very large page will therefore get proportionately penalized (quite good from my point of view as a user, because the page will load too slowly for me just as it does for Google's crawler).

Comment: Of course, Wikipedia is the true testament to the fact that this can be beaten as long as enough people link to you.

Comment: Load time is only one factor, of course -- it can't be the only one or nearly-empty, useless pages would dominate;-)

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said, page load time is an important factor. However, the page size is another important factor. You've mentioned about 70 images. I believe, search engines don't weigh images. The page size doesnt include images, when robots access them. They just see your ALT descriptions instead of images. So, you just need to weigh the page without images(still, the text description present in the ALT tag counts) and other graphical contents.

To answer your major question, the size of the file. Size is not a factor to avoid/select to search engines. But it does have a priority. They do prefer smaller files. So an optimum size for a page can be one which doesn't exceed 100K. This varies often based on the site objective and other needs.

But, my suggestion would be focus on the users than SEO. Even search engines say that. If the content will be useful for the customers, then you can always compramise SEO. Never SEO alone makes a site successful. Its good content which gets traffic.